# OOP Javascript - Accessing a privileged method from public method via another public method

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var Person = function (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.scream = function () {
    this.WhatToScream.screamAge();
}

Person.prototype.WhatToScream = function () {
    this.screamAge = function () {
        alert('I AM ' + this.age + ' YEARS OLD!!!');
    }
    this.screamName = function () {
        alert('MY NAME IS ' + this.name + '!!!')
    }
}

var man = new Person('Berna', 21);
man.scream();


// This code raises:
// Uncaught TypeError: Object WhatToScream has no method 'screamAge'
```

Comment: `WhatToScream` is a function not an object. In any case, why don't you just add the methods straight into the prototype?

Comment: I can't, my code need to handle new methods into `WhatToScream`.
Later, people are going to add like `this.screamHuh(){ alert("HUH!") }`, and this `screamHuh()` must be accessible by `scream`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a re-definiton that is closer to your original code:

```
Person.prototype.scream = function () {
  new this.WhatToScream().screamAge();
}
```

Comment: @c69 I don't know what I did, I can't make it work anymore.. I'm trying `for methods in this.WhatToScream` to get all ways to scream, I currently have 2, but it doesn't seem to retrieve a single one...

Comment: @BernaMariano should be `for (methods in (new this.WhatToScream) )` in this case

Comment: @BernaMariano: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = function (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.scream = function () {
    // get function screamAge from container WhatToScream,
    // which is available in the instance of the object,
    // because it was defined in the prototype
    // and then call it with thisArg being current this,
    // which is pointing to current container,
    // * which at runtime is man
    this.WhatToScream.screamAge.call(this);
}

Person.prototype.WhatToScream = {
    screamAge: function () {
        alert('I AM ' + this.age + ' YEARS OLD!!!');
    },
    screamName: function () {
        alert('MY NAME IS ' + this.name + '!!!')
    }
}

var man = new Person('Berna', 21);
man.scream();
```

---

If you want to keep `WhatToScream` as a function, you will need to call it to use the object it returns:

```
Person.prototype.scream = function () {
    this.WhatToScream().screamAge.call(this);
}

Person.prototype.WhatToScream = function () {
    return {
        screamAge: function () { ... }, 
        screamName: function () { ... },
    }
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone knew a solution that keeps `WhatToScream` a function... Else I'm gonna use your answer

Comment: In that case - use module pattern, see the second part of updated answer. Notice the `()`

Comment: @BernaMariano: I think you just have to re-consider your structure. It just seems reduntant.. I suggest adding all methods to the prototype and prefix them if needed like you're already doing.

Comment: @elclanrs did you see my reply to your first comment?

Comment: @c69 You updated right as I was about to submit my post, doing just that. Would be a wise idea to cache that object after the first time generating it.

Comment: @BernaMariano: Yes I did. I would still change the structure before your API becomes a mess. Keeping your current structure you'll eventually find yourself fixing the context of `this` in every other function when it gets more complex and will be harder to track closures and encapsulate your code.

Comment: @SpenserJ yes, good point, but it will (further) convolute the answer as we will get into "the hard problem cache invalidation" ;)